# How to fix terminal on Mac?

Tags: terminal, zsh

I am having trouble running any commands on Terminal. First, I had a problem running Android Emulator with Expo client but somehow i was not able to run adb command that should be enabled before running the emulator, then when I added android platform-tools by commands, I think I messed up with the default terminal. I am using zsh shell not even able to change to bash, Pleasee help me to fix this issue. Even, ls, node, npm, or any commands says **zsh: command not found:**

Everytime if i need to use commands, I need to run this **PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
command do stuffs, but after re open or new terminal, same happens**

when I do echo $PATH, it is giving me **:/Users/Username/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/Username/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/Username/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/Username/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools**

Here i do not see the default configuration, how can i fix that?

Answer (score -1):

At first, set the path environment variable manually as you are doing now,

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Then,

```
sudo nano /etc/paths
```

Now add these lines,

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

Press cntrol+x and then y .Reopen the terminal and check.

Comment: It is giving me this error " zsh: command not found: sudo ", cannot run any command i dunno why

Comment: @Ulugbek first, use PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin . Then run sudo nano /etc/paths

Comment: where shoul i save that? it says File Name to Write: /etc/paths

Comment: Same as before, I added those lines but same is happening, what can cause that problem>?

Comment: Some how your /etc/paths is being deleted or overwritten. If you create and save those lines in that file, then you should not set path variable every time you open a new terminal. Please check if the file is saved properly. If necessary, reboot the MAC.

Comment: It's highly unlikely the OP needs to edit `/etc/paths`. It's more likely that they accidentally *overwrite* the default value of `PATH` in their shell configuration, rather than adding *additional* directories to the value.

Comment: There is *absolutely* need to reboot the computer.